# What kind of colors type is this

Tags: colors

I have a MS ACCESS database from a big old project (not a web one, don't know in which language it was written), and in one table there is a field, called "color". It contains a strange type of values:

[image: Colors list]

I've searched the web for an answer, but I can't yet figure out, and the only solution that seems to work is to manually parse all elements in the old program and match all colors. This will work, but there's a lot of data, and it will consume a lot of time.

For example, color in the list **-15578478** stands for **#124A92** in HTML HEX.

Comment: Not sure about this...it doesn't appear to be the decimal version of the hex number, assuming you mapped correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear to be 32-bit ARGB displayed as signed decimal.

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('>i', -15578478))
b'ff124a92'
```

The alpha field happens to be maxed out, causing the sign of all the numbers to show as negative. It's fairly likely it isn't acting as opacity elsewhere but simply skipped.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be it. Just thought it may be a hex converted to decimal. Thank you!

Comment: So it's possible they saved a 32bit number in 24bits.

Comment: More the other way around. If the storage were 24 bit we'd likely not see any higher bits set, and 0x124a92 wouldn't be negative if read as 24 bits.